# How to shrink parent ignorint children size without errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to animate the container to height 0. And I want the children to shrink to it, but obviously it throws overflow pixels error. And I dont know how to make the children shrink without errors.

Ive tried searching some widgets like BoxContraints to make it ignore the overflow or something like that but im not even sure what to do

```dart
_topContainerHeight = _queryFieldHasFocus ? 0 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.75;

    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        stream: _authService.userStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          ConnectionState state = snapshot.connectionState;
          bool loggedIn = _authService.user != null;

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: appBar,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
                      height: _topContainerHeight,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          if (state == ConnectionState.waiting) ...[
                            CircularProgressIndicator()
                          ] else ...[
                            if (!loggedIn) ...[
                              Expanded(
                                child: RawMaterialButton(
                                  onPressed: _authService.googleSignIn,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Clique aqui para iniciar uma conta e criar excursões',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ] else ...[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Align(
                                              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                            child: FlatButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTravelPage()));
                                                },
                                                color: Colors.deepPurple.shade400,
                                                highlightColor:
                                                Colors.deepPurple.shade400,
                                                splashColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                                child: SizedBox(
                                                    width: double.infinity,
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Criar uma excursão',
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color: Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 16.0,
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w600),
                                                        ),
                                                        Icon(Icons.add,
                                                            color: Colors.white)
                                                      ],
                                                    ))),
                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]
                          ],
                        ],
                      )),
                  Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _queryFieldController,
                            focusNode: _queryFieldFocus,
                            onTap: _updateQueryFieldFocus,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Para qual evento deseja ir?'),
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

I want it to shrink

[image: snap]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SizedOverflowBox Widget, it makes effect like overflow: hidden in css.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedOverflowBox/SizedOverflowBox.html

p.s. Welcome to stackoverflow